# Trying to run C/C++ Compile Run on VSCode keeps resulting in the error "command 'extension.CompileRun' not found"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have tried uninstalling VSCode but I have no clue how to even begin to fix this problem. I also tried disabling and reenabling the extension but it still doesn't work. I even tried uninstalling and installing it again but to no avail. How do I fix this? I installed everything like the VSCode website for C++ said so I installed MinGW code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp. I'm using the g++ compiler. I put the bin folder of MinGW in my path (C:\MinGW\bin). My OS is Windows 11.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZmaC.png)

Comment: Do you have a compiler installed like GNU?

Comment: Also, when you run a debugger, what options does VSCode give you?

Comment: My compiler is g++ and I'm pretty sure the only debugger I have is GDB.

Comment: Is it installed correctly? Is it in your PATH? The question is missing information, like your OS, the compiler that's installed and how you installed it.

Comment: I installed it like the VSCode website for C++ said so I installed MinGW https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp and I'm using the g++ compiler. I put the bin folder of MinGW in my path (C:\MinGW\bin). My OS is Windows 11.

Comment: It's worth noting that comments are *not* the question. You need to edit the question with this information.

Comment: If the extension is misbehaving, did you read the documentation for the extension? Maybe it's just a garbage extension? I don't use any press-play buttons in my VS Code. The project is small enough that I can create a build task, or complex enough that I use a build system like cmake. Both instances put compilation either a keystroke or button press away.

Comment: Ok, I got the extension to work. Basically, all I did was delete the keybinding, reinstall Compile Run, and then I set the keybinding again.